# Include a layer in all generated assets

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I'm just starting to use Photoshop's Image Asset Generation feature, but can't work out how (or if it's even possible) to include a single layer in all generated images.

For example, I have a layer with a generic blank "computer screen" image on it, and I want to generate 10 sprites with that computer on them, but with maybe a different coloured icon on it.

At the moment, I have to duplicate the base layer 10 times into groups with the specific icon for each one, which then get exported. The problem with that is whenever I redesign the base image, I have to re-duplicate it to all the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turn your graphic/layer into a smart object.**

Right click on the layer -> Convert to Smart Object. Then duplicate that smart object layer and place in the various groups, make sure to NOT select "New Smart Object via Copy". Once you update one of the smart objects, every duplicate smart object layer will change as well.

To edit a smart object, double click on the thumbnail. This will open a new document window for that layer. Make sure to save when you're done editing the smart object.